# CONCAT WITH 4 COLUMNS AND EMPTY COLUMN

Tags: sql

I need concatenate 4 columns, but, in some cases I have data in these columns and sometimes not:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbeoO.png)

When to the following columns have no data, my `CONCAT` returns an empty result:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWjiK.png)

My code:

```
SELECT
    {FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT(observacao1, '')}, 
    observacao2)}, '')}, observacao3)}, '')}, observacao4)} AS OBSERVACOES 
FROM 
    Fat.CliComplemento2
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: please table with database platform, and programming language.  this is not SQL by itself.

Comment: The database is Caché(by intersystems).

Comment: use `isnull(observationN,'')` to prevent NULL from going to Observations. then you guarantee that all columns will be Strings

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
select CONCAT(
    isnull(observacao1,''), /* case when observacao1 is null use empty string */
    isnull(observacao2,''),
    isnull(observacao3,''),
    isnull(observacao4,''))
FROM Fat.CliComplemento2
```

Comment: Caché not allow "isnull" comand :/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
SELECT codEmpresa, codCliente, observacao1, observacao2, observacao3, observacao4, {FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT(coalesce(observacao1, ' '), coalesce(observacao2, ' '))}, coalesce(observacao3, ' '))}, coalesce(observacao4, ' '))} AS OBSERVAÇÃO
FROM Fat.CliComplemento2
```